# What is /home directory in Mac OS used for?

Tags: macos

I am new to Mac OS. Before I usually used Linux, and /home/your_account directory is used to store personal files, which in Mac, I found, are stored in /Users/your_account. /home is empty and it is a root directory.
Thus, I am wondering about the function of this directory. Could anyone give some advice or tips?
Thanks.

Comment: For me it is completely empty. Legacy cruft would be my guess.

Comment: Somewhat marginally related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362703/how-can-i-use-the-home-directory-on-mac-os-x?rq=1

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9341/what-are-the-empty-home-and-net-drives

Comment: Are you referring to the hidden volume?

Comment: @ArtOfWarfarea I just use terminal and the 'ls' command. It is not hidden, though in gui, we can hardly find it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Simply put, the `/home` directory is used for nothing on macOS.

While it's typically the location for user homes in Linux and Unix, macOS uses `/Users` instead. If you want to write portable programs, simply use `$HOME` or `~` to refer to the home directory.

Comment: I want to remove `/home` and create a symlink to `/Users`. But `sudo rmdir /home` always complaint `rmdir: home: Resource busy`. Why? Any solution?

Comment: @slhck, Why scribd?

Comment: @Pacerier That's the only place where this info was still available. Note that my post is from 2012 and the documentation has been deprecated in the meantime.

Comment: @FrozenFlame Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25558272/1418337).

Comment: Do you know if this expands to `~` in the shell? (Linux user here with no access to a Mac, yet)

Comment: @runlevel0 You mean the other way around, right? `~` expands to `/Users/foo` in macOS (if your username is "foo"); it's the same as `$HOME`.

Comment: Yes, I mean the other way around :facepalm:

Answer (score 2):

/home is a hidden directory and it basically doesn’t do anything. It is a ‘link’ to a shared volume mounted in /System/Volumes/home. It is completely blank and couldn’t be deleted. The reason for this point is because of the SIP, which offers protection to macOS.

If you want to do anything about it, use the ultilty->terminal in the recovery mode (press and hold command+R when the machine starts to enter). Then, close SIP and create a new ‘/home’.

upd: not /System/Volumes/home but /System/Volumes/Data/home

```
map auto_home on /System/Volumes/Data/home (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
```